# Why logoff user not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to make log off user functionality.

When user click this linq:

```
  <a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i>LogOff </a>
```

This action is called:

```
  [Authorize]
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    // POST: /Account/LogOff
    [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

While I chenge the linq above to this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(@Resources.Resources.LogOff, "LogOff", "Account", new { id = "logoutForm" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })
```

I get error:

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed,    had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.        Requested URL:
>   /MySiteName/Account/LogOff/logoutForm

Any idea why the second attitude dosent work?Why I get  logoutForm as postfix in my URL?

Answer (score 0):

The route for `/MySiteName/Account/LogOff/logoutForm` simply does not exist. You are passing in a route parameter `id` with the value `"logoutForm"` to your route, yet the action method LogOff does not accept any parameters. 
This is also excactly what the error tells you. You can verify this by looking at the signature of your action method:

```
public ActionResult LogOff() {}
```

As you can see it does not take any parameters, so the url you have to call is the same as it states in the comment just above it: `// POST: /Account/LogOff`

That in turn means, removing your route parameters, so just replace `new { id = "logoutForm" }` with `null`:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(@Resources.Resources.LogOff, "LogOff", "Account", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })
```

And you should be good to go.

I do not see a reason, why the Log out itself should be a post. You are not submitting any data to the server. You can do a simple GET, achieve the same and remove some unnessecary complexity along the way.

Comment: Thanks for post.I try yours example.But I get this error:

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
Requested URL: /MySiteName/Account/LogOff

Comment: Have you removed the post options somwhere?